# Changing extension icon in firefox menu

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm using the [FireFTP](http://fireftp.net/) extension version 2.0.24.1. Its icon in the Firefox menu is all blurry.
The fireFTP website has a [pretty icon](http://fireftp.net/images/logo64.png). I'd like to replace the blurry one with the pretty one.

For now I've tried messing with files. I think the icon is stored in `[profile directory]/extensions/{a7c6cf7f-112c-4500-a7ea-39801a327e5f}/chrome/icons/default/fireftp-main-window.ico`. Changing its name from `fireftp-main-window.ico` to `fireftp-main-window.ico.bak` however did not change the way it is displayed. I'm thinking there either a reference somewhere I should change (did not found any in `[profile directory]/extensions/{a7c6cf7f-112c-4500-a7ea-39801a327e5f}/chrome/fireftp.jar` and/or force a "refresh" on the extension by Firefox.

1. How can I most easily change the icon?
2. What image formats are supported?
3. Once satisfied with the result, what's the best way to propose the change to the FireFTP developers?

Mozilla Firefox 39.0 on Linux Mint 17.1.

Comment: It depends on how that specific addon is applying it, i would have to open it up and check it out.